# PHP MySQL Select data from two tables and Order by a field from a third table

Tags: php, mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

Please I have the following tables

```
Field
+----+--------+----------+---------------------+
| id | name   | Type     | date                |
+----+--------+----------+---------------------+
|  1 |  price | int      | 2009-09-02 00:07:07 |
|  2 |  width | float    | 2009-09-02 00:07:08 |
|  3 |  height| float    | 2009-09-02 00:07:30 |
+----+--------+--------------------------------+


Post
+----+--------+---------------------------------+
| id |title   | Body                            |
+----+--------+---------------------------------+
|  1 |  test  | Bla bla bla                     |
|  2 | Hello  | Bla bla bla                     |
|  3 | Its me | Bla bla bla                     | 
+----+--------+---------------------------------+


Post_Annex
+----+--------+----------+---------------------+
| id | IdPost | IdField  | Value               |
+----+--------+----------+---------------------+
|  1 |  1     | 1        | 50                  |
|  2 |  1     | 2        | 21                  |
|  3 |  1     | 3        | 3                   |
|  4 |  2     | 1        | 10                  |
|  5 |  2     | 2        | 2                   |
|  6 |  2     | 3        | 150                 |
|  7 |  3     | 1        | 1                   |
|  8 |  3     | 2        | 25                  |
|  9 |  3     | 3        | 15                  |
+----+--------+--------------------------------+
```

And I desire to select data from the **Post** and **Post_Annex** tables, group them by the Id of the Post table and order them by the price  (this mean by IdField of the Post_Annex table when its equal to 1). So this is my query :

```
SELECT p.title
    FROM Post p
    LEFT JOIN Post_Annex pa
       ON p.id = pa.IdPost

    GROUP BY p.id

    ORDER BY case when pa.IdField = 1 then 0 else 1, pa.Value DESC
```

This gave me the result in this order : `its Me  |  Hello | test`

This is fine. But even if I try the order by the width (IdField = 2) or height (IdField  = 3) it gave me the same result.

Please masters any Idea to help me resolving this ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just modify the join clause, to specify which field you want to sort:

```
SELECT p.title
FROM Post p
     LEFT JOIN Post_Annex pa
     ON p.id = pa.IdPost
        AND pa.idfield=1
ORDER BY pa.Value DESC
```

and then you don't have to group by p.id.

Your query doesn't always work because you are grouping by `p.id` but you are selecting (and ordering by) other nonaggregated columns, and the values of those columns can be [undetemined](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html).

Comment: The order is correct but it returns me 4 results instead of three :( (One result is repeated). Thanks

Comment: @SamiElHilali do you have some duplicated values? or maybe you need an `inner join` instead of a `left join`? using your sample data it looks like it works http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/70802/3

Comment: Yes I have a third table, But I just leave the **group by** and I add **AND pa.idfield=1** and it works very fine. (I think the Mysql extends the order by) Thank you for the explanation and the Help. +1

Answer (score 0):

In a simple SQL, avoiding group by, and case when's:

```
SELECT p.title
FROM Post p, Post_Annex pa
WHERE p.id = pa.IdPost
AND pa.IdField = 1
ORDER BY pa.Value DESC
```

You could do simply that.